# Conditional rendering of a Form.Item on Ant design

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to make a form using Ant design v4.0. The display of an Form.Item (Input text) depends of the value of other Form.Item (Radio button group). I'm using `form.getFieldValue('fieldname')` and it works initially but, when I changed the value of the radio Botton group the field is still showing up.

The code is similar to this

```js
(...)
const [form] = useForm();
(...)
<Form form={form} (...)>
    <Form.Item name="fieldname" initialValues={props.initialValues}>
        // Here it is a radio button group
    </FormItem>
    { form.getFieldValue('fieldname') === 'a_value' && (
        <Form.Item name="a-text-field> 
              // here it is an input text
        </Form.Item>
    )}
</Form>
```

As I said before, it works with the initial value but if I changed the option it doesn't work. I also try the prop in the field a-text-field but it didn't work

`hidden={form.getFieldValue('fieldname') !== 'a_value'}`

Comment: I am with the same challenge here. Did you solved using useState and conditional rendering?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-bg70lz?file=/FormList.js:0-54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this example in antd documentation.
https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks
This doesn't require any state variables. The 'shouldUpdate' prop rerenders the specific form.item.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30741224)

Answer (score 3):

it's because if the radio input changed, it does not change the form.item value so doing `form.getFieldValue('fieldname')` will not work. You may use a state instead and use onValuesChange prop of the form:

```
const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState("a_value");
const [form] = useForm();
(...)

const handleFormValuesChange = (changedValues) => {
    const fieldName = Object.keys(changedValues)[0];

    if(fieldName === "a-text-field"){
        const value = changedValues[fieldName];
        setRadioValue(value)
    } 
}

<Form form={form} onValuesChange={handleFormValuesChange}>
    <Form.Item name="fieldname" initialValues={radioValue}>
        // Here it is a radio button group
    </FormItem>
    { radioValue === 'a_value' && (
        <Form.Item name="a-text-field'> 
              // here it is an input text
        </Form.Item>
    )}
</Form>
```

here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-murdock-o5j0h?file=/index.js:468-691) of working sample

Comment: This is a good approach, thanks! but, I receive an initialValue as a prop so I can use a prop as an initial state. That's my problem =(

Comment: you can directly place the prop on state e.g. useState(props.initialValues);. You can also set the value inside useEffect: form.setFieldsValue({fieldname: props.initialValues}).

Comment: Isn't the first proposal an antipattern? I like the second one. I will try to do it.